# How to select specific value from a table that has multiple values for a record in primary key table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have three tables as follows (with sample data):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  login varchar(20),
  organization varchar(20)
);
CREATE TABLE rights (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(20)
);
CREATE TABLE user_rights_rel (
  uid int REFERENCES users,
  rid int REFERENCES rights,
  PRIMARY KEY (uid, rid)
);

-- 1-5  'A'
-- 6-10 'B'
INSERT INTO users VALUES
  (1,  'Smith',   'A'),
  (2,  'Jane',    'A'),
  (3,  'Katrin',  'A'),
  (4,  'Todd',    'A'),
  (5,  'Ervine',  'A'),
  (6,  'David',   'B'),
  (7,  'White',   'B'),
  (8,  'Anderson','B'),
  (9,  'Randi',   'B'),
  (10, 'Polak',   'B');  

INSERT INTO rights values
  (9,'Contact'),
  (62,'Download'),
  (59,'Reviewer'),
  (32,'High Reviewer'),
  (64,'Read Only'),
  (66,'Data Entry');  


INSERT INTO user_rights_rel VALUES
  (1,9),(1,64),(1,59),(1,62),
  (2,64),(2,59),(2,62),(2,66),
  (3,66),(3,62),(3,9),
  (4,66),(4,64),(4,9),
  (5,62),(5,64),(5,9),
  (6,9),(6,64),(6,62),
  (7,64),(7,62),
  (8,66),(8,9),
  (9,66),(9,64),(9,9),(9,32),
  (10,62),(10,64),(10,9);
```

Now I want to write a query based on the below criteria:

1. If a user has `Reviewer` or `High Reviewer` right along with other rights, it should be counted as `Reviewer`.
2. If a user has `Data Entry` right along with the other rights(except `Reviewer` and `High Reviewer`), it should be counted as `Data Entry User`.
3. If a user has `Read Only` right along with the other rights(except `Reviewer`, `High Reviewer` and `Data Entry`), it should be counted as `Read Only User`.

As per the above criteria, my desired output is:

```
Organization        Reviewer     Data Entry        Read Only
   A                    2            2                 1
   B                    1            1                 3
```

Organization A has 2 Reviewers (Users 1 and 2). If a user has `Reviewer` right then we count it as `Reviewer` user and we ignore other rights.

Organization A has 2 Data Entry users (Users 3 and 4). If a user does not have `Reviewer` and `High Reviewer` rights then we look for `Data Entry` right, if it has `Data Entry` right then we count it as `Data Entry` user and ignore other rights.

Organization A has 1 Read Only user (User 5). If a user does not have `Reviewer`,`High Reviewer` and `Data Entry` rights, then we look for `Read Only` right, if it has `Read Only` right then we count it as `Read Only` user and ignore other rights.

The priority should be as follows:
1. Reviewer (if a user has it, count him/her as Reviewer and ignore other rights).
2. Data Entry (if a user has it, count him/her as Data Entry and ignore other rights).
3. Read Only (If a user has it, count him/her as Read Only and ignore other rights.)

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to define your user categories with CASE and PIVOT the result:

> ```
> select organization
>      , count(*) filter (where rgt=59) "Reviewer" 
>      , count(*) filter (where rgt=66) "Data Entry" 
>      , count(*) filter (where rgt=46) "Read Only" 
> from( select users.*
>            , case when exists( select *
>                                from user_rights_rel 
>                                where uid=id and rid in(59,32) ) then 59
>                   when exists( select * 
>                                from user_rights_rel 
>                                where uid=id and rid=66 ) then 66
>                   when exists( select *
>                                from user_rights_rel 
>                                where uid=id and rid=64 ) then 46 end rgt
>       from users ) u 
> group by organization
> order by organization;
> ```
>
> ```
> organization | Reviewer | Data Entry | Read Only
> :----------- | -------: | ---------: | --------:
> A            |        2 |          2 |         1
> B            |        1 |          1 |         3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=44e603e1d73c1928dc5c907d5a9b4ee5)*

Answer (score 3):

## Single pass using `DISTINCT ON`

We can use `DISTINCT ON` in subselect to get the users highest priority rights. Then we need only count the rights by those groups.

It's important to note, we're joining to `rights` here. We needn't do that. You could adopt the method of simplicity used in [@JackDouglas's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168401/2639) to compare on `ints`. It saves a lot of time by not joining but because we only do one table scan we're still twice as fast. In production, you may want to skip the join on `rights`.

```
SELECT
  organization,
  count(rightgrp) FILTER (WHERE rightgrp = 1) AS "Reviewer",
  count(rightgrp) FILTER (WHERE rightgrp = 2) AS "Data Entry User",
  count(rightgrp) FILTER (WHERE rightgrp = 3) AS "Read Only User"
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (organization, uid)
    organization,
    uid,
    CASE
      WHEN rights.name IN ('Reviewer', 'High Reviewer') THEN 1
      WHEN rights.name IN ('Data Entry') THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END AS rightgrp
  FROM rights
  JOIN user_rights_rel
    ON rid = rights.id
  JOIN users
    ON uid = users.id
  ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
) AS t
GROUP BY organization
ORDER BY organization;

 organization | Reviewer | Data Entry User | Read Only User 
--------------+----------+-----------------+----------------
 A            |        2 |               2 |              1
 B            |        1 |               1 |              3
(2 rows)
```

## Using the [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) extension and `crosstab`

*I wouldn't use this method, it's too sledge-hammery for what you need*.

Here is a method that users crosstab for display, though it doesn't have to,

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab($$
  SELECT organization, rightgrp, count(*)
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (organization, uid)
      organization,
      uid,
      CASE
        WHEN rights.name IN ('Reviewer', 'High Reviewer') THEN 1
        WHEN rights.name IN ('Data Entry') THEN 2
        ELSE 3
      END AS rightgrp
    FROM rights
    JOIN user_rights_rel
      ON rid = rights.id
    JOIN users
      ON uid = users.id
    ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
  ) AS t
  GROUP BY organization, rightgrp
  ORDER BY 1,2
$$, $$
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) AS t(cat)
$$
) AS ct(organization text, "Reviewer" int, "Data Entry User" int, "Read Only User" int);
```

First, we **optimize the table read to a single pass** which we select only the highest-privilege rights for the (organization,user).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (organization, uid)
    organization,
    uid,
    CASE
      WHEN rights.name IN ('Reviewer', 'High Reviewer') THEN 1
      WHEN rights.name IN ('Data Entry') THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END AS rightgrp
  FROM rights
  JOIN user_rights_rel
    ON rid = rights.id
  JOIN users
    ON uid = users.id
  ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;

 organization | uid | rightgrp 
--------------+-----+----------
 A            |   1 |        1
 A            |   2 |        1
 A            |   3 |        2
 A            |   4 |        2
 A            |   5 |        3
 B            |   6 |        3
 B            |   7 |        3
 B            |   8 |        2
 B            |   9 |        1
 B            |  10 |        3
(10 rows)
```

Then we simply `GROUP BY organization, rightgrp` and select the count, like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (organization, uid)
  organization,
  uid,
  CASE
    WHEN rights.name IN ('Reviewer', 'High Reviewer') THEN 1
    WHEN rights.name IN ('Data Entry') THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 
  END AS rightgrp
FROM rights
JOIN user_rights_rel
  ON rid = rights.id
JOIN users
  ON uid = users.id
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3 

 organization | rightgrp | count 
--------------+----------+-------
 A            |        1 |     2
 A            |        2 |     2
 A            |        3 |     1
 B            |        1 |     1
 B            |        2 |     1
 B            |        3 |     3
(6 rows)
```

From there we can feed this to pivot using PostgreSQL's [`tablefunc` extension which provides `crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html). We can generate the pivot manually though using crafty `SELECT/FILTER`. Keep in mind right #1 is the highest priority

```
 organization | Reviewer | Data Entry User | Read Only User 
--------------+----------+-----------------+----------------
 A            |        2 |               2 |              1
 B            |        1 |               1 |              3
```

If you want to generate it without crosstab..

Comment: DISTINCT ON is an excellent approach here, but if I understand the OP correctly, there is a class of users that shouldn't appear in the output at all, whereas you are putting all other users in 'Read Only': http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a31df7ee8754412a544a4fd2e1a55fe2

Comment: @JackDouglas Read Only (If a user has it, count him/her as Read Only and ignore other rights.)

Comment: Your `ELSE 3` is counting users as 'Read Only' even when they don't have 'Read Only' right — it isn't obvious from the test data provided, which is why I added another user in the fiddle above.